# C: Linux to Windows: Sending text file over TCP produces not exact copy on the Windows side

Tags: c, linux, windows, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a system to gather software/hardware info on Macs to put it into a Windows-based SQLite3 database.

Schema is as following:

- agent on Mac - gather data, then sends it over Internet, using SSL, to small Linux server in DMZ (this part works as intended so far)
- Linux server connects to internal Windows server and sends the same data

And in that second point the problem occurs. Linux server connects to Windows one, alright, Windows receives the data, saves it under correct name, but the data itself are somewhat botched.

Here's one example.
This is how the entry looks at OS X / Linux:

```
Microsoft Word — Windows 8
VMware Fusion 7.1.1
```

This how the entry looks on Windows:

```
Microsoft Word â€” Windows 8
VMware Fusion 7.1.1
```

(VMWare Fusion 7.1.1 is version)
The long dash is replaced with three symbols. I suspect the encoding.

This is my code for sending a file:

```
    do {

    fgets(buf, BLEN, file_d);
    ch = feof(file_d);
    if(ch == 0){
        if((send(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0)) < 0){
            fprintf(stderr, "[%d][%s]: Error sending data.\n", getpid(), APPNAME);
            return 10;
        };
    }
    else break;

    memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

}while(!feof(file_d));
```

(where `BLEN = 1024`)

Now, I know it's not the best way to read a file (actually I think it should be `while(fgets(buf, BLEN, file_d) != NULL)`), but it worked for me (I will most probably rewrite it to be *kosher*) and I don't think it's the issue here.

Here is the Windows part:

```
while (1) {
    memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
    if ((bytes_read = recv(newsock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) > 0){
        fprintf(comp_fd, "%s", buf);
        printf("%s", buf);
        continue;
    }
    else if ((bytes_read = recv(newsock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) == 0){
        mytime = time(NULL);
        memset(&t, 0, 25);
        strncat(t, ctime(&mytime), 24);
        fprintf(log_fd, "[%lu][SERVER]: Connection with %S closed at %s.\n", GetCurrentThreadId(), temp_wstruct->s, t);
        close(newsock);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(log_fd, "[%lu][SERVER]: Error while receiving.", GetCurrentThreadId());
        close(newsock);
        fclose(log_fd);
        fclose(comp_fd);
        ExitThread(-1);
        break;
    }
}
```

As I said file is indeed received and saved, save for these weird symbols.
Could anyone please advise?

Comment: Depending on the size of the files: did you compare them on byte level (hexdump) ? This might help you to see which characters get lots / mixed up. "Beyond compare" has a mode for that, you might want to try and even post the result here

Comment: Is the Database in ANSI or UTF-8 encoding? If i get it right, the data you are sending is in UTF-8 and on the windows machine it get's converted to ANSI (either by the receiving program or the database). If it is only the database maybe you can change the encoding there to UTF-8?

Comment: Hey. Thanks for comments so fast! Actually that's just a simple text file on base of which later db transactions will be performed (forgot about that part, that app works well too, as long it's fed with proper text file i.e without these botched chars). So, I actually checked the files now and the file sent by "agent" is UTF-8, but server saves it in ASCII (but it looks alright).

Comment: read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Why do you call `recv()` again if it returns a value `<=0`?

Comment: Thanks Da Maex, I will - I like reading joelonsoftware once in a while.

Comment: Cargo-cult 'memset(&buf, 0, sizeof(buf));'.  'fprintf(comp_fd, "%s", buf);' assumption that the data contains no nulls, 'bytes_read = recv(newsock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)' assumption that the buf is not completely filled with read data and so will have a terminating nul from the cargo-cult memset:(

Comment: Fair point @alk I will think on that.

Comment: @MartinJames - could you elaborate please? I don't hide that I'm quite of a noob in C or programming for that matter and self-taught so far and I may show signs of cargo cult, but I genuinely want to learn stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When sending, you're assuming the data is null terminated:

   ```
       if((send(sockfd, buf, strlen(buf), 0)) < 0){
   ```

   You should use the count actually returned by the read method, and you shouldn't use `fgets()` for that purpose.
2. Your receive loop makes no sense. You're calling `recv()` several times and testing the result for a different condition each time, and when you get a non-failure result you aren't doing the right thing with it. It should go something like this:

   ```
   while ((bytesRead = recv(newsock, buf, sizeof buf, 0)) > 0)
   {
       write(filefd, buf, bytesRead);
   }
   if (bytesRead == -1)
   {
       perror("recv()");
   }
   // else it was zero which is end of stream, no error.
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am noob indeed. Thanks for the shakeup. That's just a part of the problem though it seems.

Comment: Hey guys. It seems my problem is solved. Thanks to that gentleman above, I fixed my receive loop and used fwrite instead of fprintf which solved the issue. Thanks everyone, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not be related to your issue now, you should keep in mind that `send/recv` might not send all data you tell them. You need [such](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#sendall) function instead(both for `send/recv`):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int sendall(int s, char *buf, int *len)
{
    int total = 0;        // how many bytes we've sent
    int bytesleft = *len; // how many we have left to send
    int n;

    while(total < *len) {
        n = send(s, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n == -1) { break; }
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total; // return number actually sent here

    return n==-1?-1:0; // return -1 on failure, 0 on success
}
```

Comment: For the Linux side: All `int`s should be of `size_t`, except `n` which sould be `ssize_t`.

Comment: Just use `sendfile()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're treating a binary file containing arbitrary data as a series of strings.  You can use `fread()/fwrite()` for binary data.

(Also noted by other posters in comments - I'm posting this as an answer so it receives better notice.)

On edit - look into [`sendfile()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) if you want to send a file over a socket connection.

Comment: That's a great thing to know! Thanks.